# I cant switch back to first person after getting off a horse

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After getting off my horse I can no longer switch back to first person. I tried the hex editor where you have to find the vampire thing and it is not there, maybe because I'm not a vampire. I tried loading a previous save but i would just stand in one place and I wouldn't be able to move.

Comment: is it stuck in 3rd person, or some other view

Comment: yes it is stuck

Comment: ok so i loaded another save but from a different game and it works fine but my original save with my 700 hours it still doesnt work even if i used save cleaner oh and im stuck in third person but when i try to switch to first person it stays for one second then goes back

Comment: Any mods installed?